# Using numbers in file A to get unique ID from file B based on the order specified by file A

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, uniq

I want to use the numbers of file `whitelist.txt` to get a unique identification number from file `list.txt` based on the order specified by file `whitelist.txt`.
Example:

```
$ cat whitelist.txt:  
2  
5  
7  
10   
11
(+8,000 more lines)

$ cat list.txt  
2  
172363  
14  
17  
612851  
172414  
172418  
172419  
172424  
19  
72457  
(+ 150,000 more lines)
```

Such that I can re-direct to a new file:

```
$ cat newfile.txt  
172363  
612851  
172418  
19   
72457  
(+8,000 more lines)
```

NOTE: This question has been modified. The answers below prior to May 5th, 2017 were based on input samples (`list.txt`) that were formatted as (e.g. first row) `>CLocus_2_Sample_` (instead of only the number 2) and the file name was `file.fa` (not `file.txt`).

Comment: There is something really confusing in this question. You say `I have 70 samples so every CLocus_# (e.g. >CLocus_2) repeats 70 times before the next one.` . If it is like this and you have 70 lines starting with CLocus_2 in file `list.fa`, the first 6 lines of file 'list.txt' (entries 2-5-7-10-47-67) if these entries represent Line Numbers of file `list.fa` (looks like this) , then all these lines will return CLocus_2 and will not return the expected output you provide in your question. You need to elaborate this question a lot.

Comment: I simplified my question, I used R to get only unique IDs so now there are no repeats, letters or underscores (CLocus_), just numbers

Comment: I do. I added a Note so that the prior help is still useful.

Comment: Thanks for the latest try, although it didn't work :(

Comment: Does `sed` really give you an error message saying `ed`?

Comment: I had non-unix line endings set. It worked fine after I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the revised data, try something like this:

```
$ sed -nf <(sed 's/.*/&p/g' whitelist.txt) list.txt >newfile.txt
```

This transforms the entries of `whitelist.txt` file from i.e `2` to `2p` which instructs outer `sed` to print that line `2` ==> equals to `sed -n '2p'` ==> prints the second line.
The same happens for all entries of `whitelist.txt`, creating a sed script (feeding outer sed with process substitution), containing `2p`,`5p`,`7p`,etc and those lines of list.txt are printed.

Alternative: Pre-process the whitelist.txt:

```
sed 's/.*/&p/g' whitelist.txt >whitelist2.txt  #or sed -i '....' whitelist.txt to overwrite whitelist.txt
sed -nf whitelist2.txt list.txt # you can redirect output to >newfile.txt
```

Comment: As is written I am getting this error (I'm using Cygwin): 'ed: file /dev/fd/63 line 1: unknown command: `

Comment: @Alan you are using `sed` , not `ed` right?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as you wrote it. sed is also working in cygwin as typing sed alone gives me the usage information

Comment: @Alan Does not make sense not to work. What about this : `sed -n '2p' list.txt` ??

Comment: @Alan Is cygwin using bash or it is a different shell?

Comment: @Alan you can give a try to my alternative proposal . The `<(  )` trick is a bash trick (process substitution) and maybe is not working well on cygwin.

Comment: @Alan I suspect that you have `\r` (carriage return) chars in your `list.txt` file. You can test all solutions (awk/sed) here by replacing `list.txt` with `<(tr -d '\r' <list.txt)` just for testing. Also for the second sed that gives an error instead of `sed -nf` you can try `sed -n -f` or even just `sed -f` (just for testing again)

Comment: You were completely right about the carriage return error. I looked in the text editor and it showed some of the files were using windows. I changed it to Unix and the alternative sed solution now works perfectly and I suspect all other solutinos will too. Sorry about the rookie mistake and thank you for all your time and help. I will show this in my question.

Comment: @AlanGarciaElfring So , all good now. You can upvote helpers if you like and you should accept as solution  the answer that worked for you (awk or sed or perl)

Answer (score 2):

In reply to your latest revision:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{z[$1]; next}FNR in z' whitelist.txt list.txt >newfile.txt
```

Comment: Using the numbers of the list.txt file above, I want to extract the 2nd (i.e. 172363), 5th (i.e. 612851), 7th (i.e. 612851), 10th (i.e.19), and so on, CLocus identifier from the list.fa file and insert them in a new file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlanGarciaElfring - please _stop_ posting code in the comment blocks. Use the edit button under your post to add new information. What do you mean by using the asterisk as a wildcard ? And btw, what's your OS ?

Comment: I mean using the asterisk to match specific characters like CLocus. I'm using Cygwin on a PC

Comment: @don_crissti Don't we need a sort before uniq...? Maybe not - i am a bit confused with this question.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou - _not only you don't need it, you actually don't want to `sort` here_ because it would mess the order of those IDs. Now, the Q says for each `CLocus_ID` there are 70 consecutive lines with same ID and different samples e.g. `>CLocus_2_Sample1_`, `>CLocus_2_Sample2_` ...`>CLocus_2_Sample70_` and `uniq` works with consecutive lines so no need to `sort` (assuming you extract those IDs). With such an input file based on OP's example my code works fine but OP prolly uses DOS CR/LF files or who knows what...

Comment: @don_crissti OK. Your understanding and proposed solution seems correct to me. By the way, maybe OP need to perform a "global" dos2unix transformation to overcome CR issues (if this is the case)

Comment: @Alan If you remove the last redirection part of this solution `>newfile.txt` does it print on your screen anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything without the redirection either.

Answer (score 1):

With the new specs that you are talking about, we need to modify it:

```
perl -e '
   $h{s/\n//r}++ for qx[cat ${\+shift}];
   $h{$.} && print while <>;
' whitelist.txt list.txt
```

### Explanation

- First populate the `hash` `%h` using the contents of `whitelist.txt` file which is the first argument that needs to be passed to the `Perl` code. Note that the `qx[]` operator is nothing but the `backquote` operator.
- Then we print the lines of the 2nd argument, viz., `list.txt` file whose line numbers are a member of the `hash` `%h`. Note: Since $. is always numeric AND > 0, is the reason we can get away with using just `$h{$.}` rather than the propah `exists $h{$.}`

### Results

```
172363
612851
172418
19
72457
```

Comment: This worked although for some reason it would omit the last number of list.txt, so that if list.txt asked for 10 numbers it would only print out the first 9.

Comment: I simplified my question, now there are no repeats, letters or underscores (e.g. CLocus_), just the numbers in question.

Comment: @AlanGarciaElfring I have modified the code to meet the new format.